# Setting fabric8/s2i-java version with fmp

Tags: fabric8, s2i

What is the best way to set fabric8/s2i-java image version in fmp? Maybe a property exists to override it?
So far the only way I found is like in [this](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-maven-plugin/blob/6f29f82a1c370ddf7711f500d47ff398e823fdae/samples/xml-config/pom.xml#L242) example where image name, base image, assembly and env are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily set the base image of any fabric8-maven-plugin generator with the property `fabric8.generator.from` and specify the full version here, too.

Alternatively, you can add it to the configuration of the generator itself. Assuming you are using `spring-boot`, add this to your plugin configuration:

```xml
<configuration>
  <generator>
    <config>
      <spring-boot>
       <from>fabric8/s2i-java:2.0.0</from>
      </spring-boot>
    </config>
  <generator>
</configuration>
```